# ( sed command)-> sed $foo

Tags: sed

I am writing a script that uses the sed command to replace in a file the specific identifier. Currently the script has the sed commands hard coded

Ex Current  Method:

```
s*ed 's/@Number@/ '  "${Number}" '/g; s/@Value@/ ' "${Value}" '/g; 
        s/@Socket@/ ' "${Socket}" '/g' File_Template > index.html*
```

Due to the fact that the sed command will not be hard coded anymore and we are running a lot of processes with different sed requirements, I will like to do something like this

Goal:

```
INITIALIZE_SED_COMMAND='s/@Number@/ ' "${Number}" '/g;
        s/@Value@/ ' "${Value}" '/g; 
        s/@Socket@/ ' "${Socket}" '/g;'
# Some logic happens here
INITIALIZE_SED_COMMAND="$INITIALIZE_SED_COMMAND File_Template > index.html"  ;

sed $INITIALIZE_SED_COMMAND
```

This worked in a Linux platform as a `.sh` script but I need to do it in .`ksh unix`and I keep getting cannot parse through.

ERROR:

sed: Cannot find or open file s/@Number@/npdsfg/g;.

sed: Cannot find or open file s/@Value@/SQR.

sed: Cannot find or open file #s/@Socket/semi_/g;.

Comment: sed function cannot parse

Comment: I just want to be able to keep the substitution of the sed command in a variable and when finish adding to the variable , execute the sed command with the variable holding the string

Comment: sed $variable -> where variable= all the fancy substitutions ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a consequence of moving from a Linux-based system to some non-Linux based system (AIX, perchance?). It's a fundamental misunderstanding of how the shell parses and executes commands.

You cannot write this and expect it to write a timestamp to a file:

```
v="date > /tmp/date.txt"
$v
```

Similarly you cannot write this and have it perform substitutions and write the results to an output file

```
v="s/abc/XYZ/ /tmp/source > /tmp/destination"
sed $v
```

The file redirection cannot not be specified within the variable.

What I think you're looking for is `sed -f`, where you can create a file of substitutions and have them applied to a source datafile:

```
#!/bin/ksh
# Usage: thisprogram  <transform_file>  <src_file>  <dst_file>
#
transform="$1"
src="$1"
dst="$2"

sed -f "$transform" "$src" >"$dst"
```

The transform file might contain operations like these:

```
s/@Number@/1234/g
s/@Value@/somevalue/g
s/@Socket@/99b44/g
```

Obviously you'd have to prepare this within the context of the particular execution.

With more detail in your question it might be possible to take this solution further, but I trust you have enough information here to rework it for your particular use case.

Comment: Thank You Mate, your explanation was marvelous.Cheers mates and have a wonderful day all